# Allow Cloudflare to cache my index page from Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies, cloudflare, setcookie

I'm facing a crazy problem, I've a website running on production and I'm trying to cache my index page using "Page Rules" from cloudflare to speed it up, it does not have dynamic content right now.

The problem is that it does not work probably because laravel always return the view with the XSRF-TOKEN and cloudflare will understand it as not-cachable, I already changed the header (cache-control: max-age=36000, public) but cloudflare always return the header "cf-cache-status: BYPASS) when it should return HIT.

When i try to use the same rule on a file from laravel public folder (the same php file of the view) it works ok and returns HIT.

The solution I can think is trying to remove this XSRF-TOKEN from the header response, but I'm going crazy on how to do this, any tips?

Obs: i tried removing those cookies using

```
            \Config::set('session.driver' , 'array');
            \Config::set('cookie.driver', 'array');
```

But this remove only one cookies not the XSRF-TOKEN one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to remove the CSRF token on pages you want to cache, or implement some sort of JavaScript solution where the CSRF token is being requested the moment you need it.

I found this article that explains your situation (bottom of the article):

https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-curious-case-of-caching-csrf-tokens/

If you are sure that your page does not need the CSRF token (i.e. it doesnt contain any POST/PUT/DELETE functionalities), you can remove the token for that particular page and be fine.

In Laravel, the CSRF-token is managed by `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`, which should be listed in your middleware in `\App\Http\Kernel`. Removing this middleware will remove it for all routes that use that middleware; so you'll likely have to create a separate middleware-group for pages where you *do* need CSRF protection.

You might also be able to add to the `protected $except = []` property on your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware class. This property contains an array of urls that should be excluded from CSRF verification. So you could add `'/'` to that array, or a wildcard like `'/webhook/*'`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is, how do i remove the token?

Comment: Sorry, I've added it to the answer